# Backbone: Collection nested in a model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I will list some code and explain the situation.
**(1)** I instantiate the `App.views.tasks`. In the `initialize` function of this view, I fetch the tasks.
**(2)** From the `render` function, I instantiate a `App.views.task` for each task.
 **(3)** In the `initialize` function of `App.views.task`, I instantiate an `App.views.comments` and I pass to it the collection of comments and the reference to the `DOM` element, where the task is rendered.
**(4)** `App.views.comments` kicks the fetching of the comments of the task.

**Question**:
The reference to the `DOM` element that I pass to the `App.views.comments` would be `undefined` if there wasn't the delay induced by the `fetching` of the comments.
If I passed the reference `el` in the `render` function, everything would be fine, but that also means that `App.views.comments` is instantiated every time `render` is called, which is not fine.  So this is only a lucky way to do it, it only gets the chance to have it defined because there is a `fetching`, otherwise it would be `undefined`.
I added some comments that explain in place what happens, you can find them in `App.views.task` and `App.views.comments`.

**What is the best way to solve this possible in some cases issue?**

```
App.collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.models.Task,
        url: App.baseHrefReq + '/tasks/all'
});
App.models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
initialize: function() {
            this.set({comments: new App.collections.taskComments});
            this.get('comments').url = App.baseHrefReq + '/comments/get/task-id/' + this.get('id');
        }
});
App.views.tasks = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            App.iCollections.Tasks = new App.collections.Tasks;

            App.iCollections.Tasks.bind('reset', this.render, this);
            App.iCollections.Tasks.bind('add', this.renderTask, this);

            App.iCollections.Tasks.fetch();
        },
        render: function() {
            $('.feed-list').html('');
            App.iCollections.Tasks.each(this.renderTask);

        },
        renderTask: function(task) {
            var view = new App.views.task({model: task});
            $('.feed-list').append(view.render().el);
        }
    }); 
    App.iViews.tasks = new App.views.tasks;

App.views.task = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        template: _.template($('#task-item-template').html()),
        initialize: function() {
            this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
            this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
            this.model.get('comments').bind('reset', this.render, this);
            this.model.get('comments').bind('add', this.render, this);
            this.model.get('comments').bind('remove', this.render, this);
            //I pass the DOM reference here
            this.commentsView = new App.views.comments({collection: this.model.get('comments'), el: this.$el}); 
        },
        render: function() {
            var modelJSON = this.model.toJSON();
            //the DOM reference is only ready and defined here
            this.$el.html(this.template(modelJSON)); 


            return this;
        }
});
App.views.comments = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderComment');

            this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
            this.collection.bind('add', this.renderComment, this);
            this.collection.bind('remove', this.remove, this);

            this.collection.fetch();

        },
        render: function() {
            //if there wasn't the fetch() above, $el would be undefined at this point
            this.$el.find('.feed-comments ul').html('');
            this.collection.each(this.renderComment);

        },
        renderComment: function(comment) {
            var view = new App.views.comment({model: comment});
            this.$el.find('.feed-comments ul').append(view.render().el);
        }
    });
});
App.views.comment = Backbone.View.extend({...})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to move this line `this.commentsView = new App.views.comments({collection: this.model.get('comments'), el: this.$el});` to the end of the `App.views.task.render()`.

In fact this line is part of a *rendering* behavior so this is better place for it.

Doing this you also con do it this way:

```
this.commentsView = new App.views.comments({collection: this.model.get('comments'), el: this.$el.find('.feed-comments ul')});
```

What I think it is asking for.

You should do more things like call `this.commentsView.render()` also in the `App.views.task.render()` but I think you can follow me from here.